# Unable to download my files from my folder using PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm currently using localhost to run my pages and currently I am trying to download the files my users have uploaded and stored in a folder called uploaded_files

this is the code for my download page which isn't working and I'm not quite sure what's wrong.

```
<?php

$file = $_GET['file'];

if (file_exists($file)) {
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file) . "\";");
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($name));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile("C:\xampp\htdocs\FYPproject\uploaded_files/".$file); //showing the path to the server where the file is to be download
    exit;
} else {
    echo "Download failed";
    echo $file;
}
?>
```

Comment: "Doesn't work". Do you see "Download failed" or some other error? Btw. You are checking `file_exists($file)` without the full path but use `readfile()` with the full path...  and the last / should be \. And you should do \\ instead of \. :)

Comment: What does PHP error log say?

Comment: This will help you:  http://www.media-division.com/the-right-way-to-handle-file-downloads-in-php/

Answer (score 0):

`file_exists()` need to receive the path of the file, if the file name is `"test"` and it's in `"uploaded_files/"` so you need to check `file_exists("uploaded_files/test")`. You don't need to pass the whole path if your php is already in `"FYPproject"` folder. It's the same for downloading files, you don't need to pass the whole path for `readfile()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a file path with backward slashes and forward slashes to `readfile`. Even if this is not the cause of your problem you should change it. Change it to this:

`readfile("C:\xampp\htdocs\FYPproject\uploaded_files\".$file);`

Answer (score 0):

Not all browsers support `application/force-download` so in this case try replacing the above code with `application/octet-stream` and see if it works